# Sort 24 Hour Time

Tags: vb.net, sorting, time

EDIT: It's actually an array of strings. I think if I convert to integer before sorting it should work...

EDIT 2: I've got the array converting to Int so I can sort by Int, now I just need to figure out how to make it work with the one actual string in the array.

```
Dim test As IList(Of Integer) = etaTimeSorted.ConvertAll(Function(str) Int32.Parse(str))
```

How can I sort an array of 24 hour times? When I sort them they are actually just numbers (0945 as opposed to 09:45). I'm using vb.net sort() method:

```
array.sort()
```

And it's sorting like this:

```
0001
0010
0100
1000
0102
1100
0112
1130
```

This is driving me nuts. I feel like I should have found the answer to my question on Google a long time ago. I thought maybe one of the sort overloads would be useful, but it doesn't look that way.

Comment: What is the type of the data?

Comment: Can you show us some code? Because I don't think you're using array.sort() correctly.

Comment: If it's an option, converting to military-time (0:00-23:59) first would solve this without having to implement your own compare method.

Comment: It looks as if you're doing string comparisons on the integer values. So for example comparing 1100 with 112 is actually comparing "1100" with "112" which results in the behaviour you describe.

Comment: After your first edit, it looks like you would be better off having the data type as a DateTime. You have an array with a name starting with "eta", which I take to be estimated time of arrival. If the ETA were to be some time in the following day, surely that should be sorted after today's times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
etaTimeIntSort = etaTimeSorted.ConvertAll(Function(str) Int32.Parse(str))
etaTimeIntSort.Sort()
etaTimeSorted = etaTimeIntSort.ConvertAll(Function(int) Convert.ToString(int))
```

Converted the array to int, sorted, then converted back to string so I could insert my "Blank" item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own class that implements `IComparer(Of String)`.
`Sort()` uses this interface to compare pairs of strings and find the order that they belong in.

Answer (score 0):

Could do it using LINQ, but I don't know how to do this in VB though, sorry:

```
nums.Select (n => new { Hour = n.Substring(0,2), Minute = n.Substring(2)}).OrderBy (n => n.Hour).ThenBy (n => n.Minute ).Select (n => n.Hour + n.Minute)
```